# Create multiple new data.frame columns in R using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(text=c('my_text', 'looks_like_this', 'I_want_to_split_it'))
```

I want to use some kind of `dplyr` family function to make a dataframe that looks like this:

```
newdf <- data.frame(text=c('my_text', 'looks_like_this', 'I_want_to_split_it'),
                    W1=c('my', 'looks', 'I'),
                    W2=c('text', 'like', 'want'),
                    W3=c(NA, 'this', 'to'),
                    W4=c(NA, NA, 'split'),
                    W5=c(NA, NA, 'it'))
```

I'm thinking something like this:

```
newdf <- df %>%
  mutate(WX=strplit(text, '_'))
```

But cant quite figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `strsplit` and then do `NA` padding at the end

```
lst1 <- strsplit(as.character(df$text), "_")
out <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, lapply(lst1, `length<-`, max(lengths(lst1))))
names(out) <- paste0("W", seq_along(out))
cbind(df, out)
```

---

Or  another option is `read.table`

```
cbind(df, read.table(text = as.character(df$text), sep="_", header = FALSE,
      fill = TRUE, col.names = paste0("W", 1:5)))
```

---

With `tidyverse`, we can use `separate`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
      separate(text, into = str_c("W", 1:5), fill = 'right', remove = FALSE)
#               text    W1   W2   W3    W4   W5
#1            my_text    my text <NA>  <NA> <NA>
#2    looks_like_this looks like this  <NA> <NA>
#3 I_want_to_split_it     I want   to split   it
```

Or after doing the `strsplit` based on the OP's code, use `unnest_wider`

```
df %>%
   mutate(WX = strsplit(as.character(text), "_")) %>% 
   unnest_wider(WX, names_repair = ~c('text', str_c("W", 1:5)))
```

---

Or using `cSplit`

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(df, "text", "_")
```